# Find Attendees of an Event

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to display events from a "public" google calendar. My requirement is to get the number of attendees (not necessarily the names of the attendees). However, when I get the events using the Calendar API (using an API Key and CalendarID); the event is missing the whole attendees section that is mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events).

My question: Do I need to be authenticated ? Does this mean this can't be public, and the web-pages that displays this information will need the "viewer" to authenticate to Google first?

Here is a snippet of my code (edited)...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarId+ '/events?key=' + myKey),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //here is where I need to get the number of participants
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    //tell that an error has occurred
  }
```

Here is the output...

{kind: 'calendar#events', etag: '"p324e9j5nqabva0g"', summary: 'EDWC Schedule', description: '', updated: '2022-01-04T08:09:10.933Z', …}
accessRole: 'reader'
defaultReminders: (0) []
description: ''
etag: '""'
items: (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {kind: 'calendar#event', etag: '""', id: '', status: 'confirmed', htmlLink:…}
1: {kind: 'calendar#event', etag: '""', id: '', status: 'confirmed', htmlLink:…}
conferenceData: {}
created: ''
creator: {}
description: ''
end: {dateTime: '2022-01-08T16:00:00+11:00', timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney'}
etag: ''
eventType: 'default'
hangoutLink: ''
htmlLink: ''
iCalUID: ''
id: ''
kind: 'calendar#event'
location: 'Australia'
organizer: {email: '', displayName: '', self: true}
sequence: 0
start: {dateTime: '2022-01-08T13:00:00+11:00', timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney'}
status: 'confirmed'
summary: ''
updated: '2022-01-04T08:09:10.933Z'
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
kind: 'calendar#events'
nextSyncToken: 'CIjkzLfSl_UCEAAYASCvg6XIAQ=='
summary: ''
timeZone: 'Australia/Melbourne'
updated: '2022-01-04T08:09:10.933Z'
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [Google Api Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/calendar/classes/Resource$Events.html#get) in this manner:

| Google Calendar Event Attendees | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70620780) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const calendarClient = googleClient.calendar('v3');

// Update the below fields with your desired values
const calendarId = 'YOUR_CALENDAR_ID';
const eventId = 'YOUR EVENT_ID';

const response = await calendarClient.events.get({
  calendarId,
  eventId,
});

const attendees = response.data.attendees;
```

Answer (score 0):

- As per your question, the answer is yes. Every request sent to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token. Now, that authorization does not always entail a **consent screen**, it can also be a short-lived **access token** or an **API key** (like in your example). I would encourage you to read more about the authorization process [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth).
- As per your code snippet and response, the events list is located inside the items property of the response object. [Here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) you can find how the response object is structured, but in a nutshell, you can access the events by looping through the items like this:

```js
for (var event of response['items']){}
```

Comment: I did not ask how I can access the items; I am looking for the "attendees" which don't seem to appear using the API key option.