# Google Calendar API not returning attendees when listing events

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

When retrieving events using the Google Calendar Api v3 the attendees array is not included in the results. I'm authenticating with a service account, so there should be no access restrictions on individual fields.

My request looks like this (authentication code omitted for brevity):

```js
async function fetchEvents() {
  const calendar = google.calendar('v3')
  google.options({ auth: await auth() })

  return await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId:
      '<the-actual-calendar-id>@group.calendar.google.com',
    fields:
      'items(summary,description,attendees)',
    maxAttendees: 99,
    timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
    maxResults: 5,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  })
}
```

Omitting the `fields` parameter entirely also doesn't include the attendees although the field is part of the [Events Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events?hl=en).

Likewise, omitting `maxAttendees` also doesn't change anything.

Following the htmlLink returned from the API, I can verify that a particular event has a list of attendees.

Comment: If your using a service account did you remember to delegate to a user?  Can i see your authorization code?

Comment: Seems a related question was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620780/find-attendees-of-an-event Does the calendarClient.events.get method works for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have not set up [delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/domain#domain_resources_and_rooms) properly.  When you delegate to the user in your workspace domain.  That user has access on the domain for `the-actual-calendar-id>@group.calendar.google.com`

Then you init impersonation with the with_subject .

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.org')
```

Comment: Yes, that was in fact the issue. The attendees can only be retrieved by impersonating the user that owns the calendar. I'll post a separate answer since it involves a few steps to actually set this up and implement it with the Node SDK.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [DalmTo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080071/9326993) an event's attendees is a privileged field that can't be retrieved with a service account unless it is used to impersonate the calendar's owner.

#### Setting up a service account to impersonate a user

1. [Enable domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en) for the service account in the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/ac/owl). The OAuth scope required is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events`.
2. Use `google.auth.JWT` to impersonate the user (from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1699#issuecomment-812411745)):

```js
  const auth = google.auth.JWT({
    subject: 'user@your-workspace-domain.com',
    keyFile: '/path/to/service-account-keyfile.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
  })

  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth })

  const { data } = await calendar.events.list({ ... })
```